# Strophe.js unable to connect to XMPP server using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xmpp, strophe, instant-messaging

I am building a client side application that uses XMPP for that I am connection through Strophe.js but unable to do so.

Please note that I am new to XMPP.

Code that I am using

```js
(function($){ 

// create connection
        var conn = new Strophe.Connection('https://xm3.mysite.net:5280/http-bind');
        conn.connect('myname@mysite.net', '123456', function (status) {
            if (status === Strophe.Status.CONNECTED) {
                console.log('Connection created!');
            }else if (status == Strophe.Status.CONNFAIL) {
               console.log('Connection Failed!');
            }else if (status === Strophe.Status.DISCONNECTED) {
                console.log('Connection terminated!');
            }else {
                console.log('Connection was not able to go-through!!');
                console.log(status);
            }
        }); 
})(jQuery);
```

I have also tried adding SSL as protocol to the connection object

```js
var conn = new Strophe.Connection('https://xm3.mysite.net:5280/http-bind', {protocol: "ssl"});
```

In return I am getting the error of "Connection was not able to go-through!"

[image]

Return status is 1, which I also want to know what this means or if there is specific link which layouts the meaning of error codes returned.

Important point to note here is CONNFAIL is actually not being called which is strange, have also tried CONNECTING status which is being fired if used.

Comment: did you cross check your `bosh-http-url` or `port` ? Is it `5280` ? You can check these settings in `server > server settings > HTTP bindings`. Are you using `openfire` or another server ?

Comment: @Vineet Yes, server settings are correct. I am using `ejabberd` for server.

Comment: Basically `HTTP binding allows clients using the HTTP protocol to connect to the server.`. Strophe use these ports to connect. Make sure your server allow these requests. Default port is `7070`. In this case your URL should look like `http://domain.com:7070/http-bind/`. Use this URL and try again

Comment: @Vineet Just tried that, same message. Please note in this case I am working with HTTPS, will that requires code changes anyhow ?

Comment: then try with `7443` instead of `7070`.

Comment: can you directly post your url  https://xm3.mysite.net:5280/http-bind/?<body rid="1"/> in browser, and check its working or not.

Comment: @ButaniVijay It is working fine now, there was some issue from the server side.